# Which process owns the given port (Linux kernel)?

Tags: c++, linux-kernel, network-programming, netfilter

I am writing a simple application layer firewall for Linux (nothing fancy for now, just sth I need). As the owner module for iptables isn't sufficient, I decided to do it with libnetfilter_queue. At some point in my firewall (C/C++ application) I need to decide wheather the packet with given src/dest port is to be accepted or not. Now comes the question. Is there any easy/fast way of knowing which process owns given port?

Basically, I need a function

```
pid_t port2pid(u_int16_t port)
```

It seems the only way to do it in userspace is to parse the `/proc` hierarchy. I don't want to do that, as it may be slow with all the ephemeral ports. The kernel must have some kind of map port->process in the TCP stack. Is it possible to get to that through, say, a custom kernel module? Maybe someone can point me to another way of accomplishing the same task?

Comment: You might also be intrested in /proc/net/tcp but you should know that userspace programs can share fds, transfer them to each other and dup() them, and as thus within the kernel there is likely on a mapping from fd+pid to kernel-filedescriptor, not the other way round.

Comment: It seems that `/proc/net` was not mentioned in all the other answers I've looked at. Also, I've found the `ss` utulity and its source is quite interesting. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Unfortunately, `ss` also parses `/proc/*/fd/*` for socket owners. How does the kernel know which process to send data to, when it arrives for a given port? A socket might be shared, yet somehow the kernel knows what to do with the data. I can't believe it looks at every process in sequence.

Comment: thats too much for SO comments and maybe even not good for an SO question, but keep in mind that to interact with the kernel, the userspace intiates any action by using an fd parameter, the kernel doesnt "send" anything.

Comment: Why is SO not the right pace? I've just hoped for a nudge in the right direction. You are right, userspace initiates sending, but what if the data arrives **from** the network (say HTTP reply for a browser). Then the port number is the only link to the actual process waiting for the data. Hence there has to be a way to map port to process.

Comment: Note that I said "maybe". SO is a place for asking specific questions about programming problems you face. Asking for explanation of the inner workings of a kernel (in a certain version) is probably in a gray area.

Comment: Only now have I understood your comment above. Indeed, the userspace always initiates, even with `recv`. I will write a self-answer.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to self.

The file `proc/net/tcp` is made available by the kernel module `tcp_diag`. It gives a readily available list of all TCP sockets and their state.

The best way to map the sockets to processes is through the file descriptors in `/proc/*/fd/*`, as the socket might be shared by many processes/threads that use them concurrently. Source to the `ss` utility from the iproute2 package is a good place to learn this stuff.