# How to find out which port number a process is using and the process using a specific port number

Tags: linux, localhost, openhab

I'm beginner with openhab, after launching the server `/etc/init.d/openhab2 start` i got that `[ ok ] Starting openhab2 (via systemctl): openhab2.service`, but I still have no access to the platform via `http://localhost:8080/`
I want to know :

> which **process** is using port **8080**
>
> which **port** **openhab** runs on

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which process owns the given port (Linux kernel)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24554696/which-process-owns-the-given-port-linux-kernel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `lsof`,

`lsof | grep TCP | grep 8080` and `lsof | grep openhab | grep TCP`

if a process forks and the child process is the one that is using a port it may not work as expected